# Child view controller not responsive

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, parent-child

I've a child view controller (from a storyboard) to a parent view controller (from a .xib file) as such:

[image]

**parentViewController.m:**

```
// creating a box for the child view controller
CGFloat screenWidth = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
CGFloat screenHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
CGFloat yOffset = self.view.frame.origin.y;
CGRect childBox = CGRectMake(0, screenHeight - yOffset, screenWidth, 0);

// adding the child view controller to the parent
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"child" bundle:nil];
ChildViewController *childVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"childViewController"];
childVC.view.bounds = childBox; 
// childVC.view.frame to self.view.bounds // <- this is an alternative
[self addChildViewController: childVC];
[self.view addSubview:childVC.view];
```

But, result is a UI where "Button 2" in the child view controller is completely unresponsive while "Button 1" in the parent view controller is.

I've also tried setting "childVC.view.frame" to "self.view.bounds" instead of "childBox" (as depicted in the 3rd to last line in the code above) and while "Button 2" in the child view controller is responsive, the child view controller completely covers up the parent view controller.

Can someone tell me how I can shrink the child view controller while allowing both buttons to be responsive to the user?

Comment: `childBox`'s height is 0, that's why

Comment: That's exactly right, @EricQian!  Thanks so much!

Comment: childVC.view.bounds = childBox;  the wrong think